# smooth auto scroll by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoscroll

I am trying to implement some code on my web page to auto-scroll after loading the page. I used a Javascript function to perform auto-scrolling, and I called my function when the page loads, but the page is still not scrolling smoothly! Is there any way to auto scroll my page smoothly?

Here is my Javascript function:

```
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's not smooth because you've got the scroll incrementing by 50 every 100 milliseconds.

change this and the amount you are scrolling by to a smaller number to have the function run with the illusion of being much more 'smooth'.

turn down the speed amount to make this faster or slower.

```
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,1);
    scrolldelay = setTimeout(pageScroll,10);
}
```

will appear to be much smoother, try it ;)

Comment: can u tell me a way in this code so that i can stop the auto scrolling when user uses mouse to scroll

Comment: if this is the correct answer then be sure to mark it so ;)

also, that would require another function done most easily using jquery and checking it as an event

Comment: I suggest not passing a string to `setTimeout` as that is equivalent to calling `eval('pageScroll')`

use something like 

`setTimeout(function(){       //coolcodehere    }, 10)`

where you pass a function to setTimeout, not a string

Comment: @johnnyutah The latter was the aim. This seems to have been a typo on my end, sorry.

Comment: The example results in a stackoverflow, you may want to remove the function call of `pageScroll` and instead pass it directly to `setTimeout` without invoking

Comment: How to add mouse in and out functionality for this?

Comment: scrollBy supports a 'behavior' dict that can set scrolling to `smooth` or `auto`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions/behavior

Comment: A ~40ms timeout should suffice since that creates 24 frames per second which is enough for a "smooth" scroll effect.

Answer (score 13):

Try to use jQuery, and this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 156}, 800); 
});
```

156 - position scroll to (px), from top of page.
800 - scroll duration (ms)

Comment: Just a correction, 800 is the duration of the animation, not the speed

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the source code for the [jQuery ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plug-in, which scrolls smoothly. Or maybe even just use the plug-in instead of rolling you own function.

Answer (score 1):

Smoothly running animations depends on the clients machine. No matter how fairly you code, you will never be satisfied the way your animation runs on a 128 MB Ram system.

Here is how you can scroll using jQuery:

```
$(document).scrollTop("50");
```

You might also want to try out [AutoScroll Plugin](https://github.com/wilkerlucio/jquery-autoscroll).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `jfunc` function to do this.
use `jFunc_ScrollPageDown` and `jFunc_ScrollPageUp` function.
http://jfunc.com/jFunc-Functions.aspx.

Comment: jfunc.com domain is for sale

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged the question as 'jquery', why don't you try something like `.animate()`? This particular jquery function is designed to smoothly animate all sorts of properties, including numeric CSS properties as well as scroll position.

Comment: Maybe he meant that the solution could be written in either jQuery or pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

the numbers are hardcoded, but the idea is to move item by item (and header is 52px) and when is down, go back

```
let elem = document.querySelector(".spfxBirthdaysSpSearch_c7d8290b ");
let lastScrollValue = 0
let double_lastScrollValue = 0
let scrollOptions = { top: 79, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }
let l = console.log.bind(console)

let intScroll = window.setInterval(function() {
    double_lastScrollValue = lastScrollValue //last
    lastScrollValue = elem.scrollTop // after a scroll, this is current
    if (double_lastScrollValue > 0 && double_lastScrollValue == lastScrollValue){
        elem.scrollBy({ top: elem.scrollHeight * -1, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
    } else {
        if (elem.scrollTop == 0){
            elem.scrollBy({ top: 52, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
        } else {
            elem.scrollBy(scrollOptions);
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take on this, using `requestAnimationFrame`. It gives you control of the scroll time, and supports easing functions. It's pretty robust, but fair warning: there's no way for the user to interrupt the scroll.

```
// Easing function takes an number in range [0...1]
// and returns an eased number in that same range.
// See https://easings.net/ for more.
function easeInOutSine(x) { return -(Math.cos(Math.PI * x) - 1) / 2; }

// Simply scrolls the element from the top to the bottom.
// `elem` is the element to scroll
// `time` is the time in milliseconds to take.
// `easing` is an optional easing function.
function scrollToBottom(elem, time, easing)
{
  var startTime = null;
  var startScroll = elem.scrollTop;
  // You can change the following to scroll to a different position.
  var targetScroll = elem.scrollHeight - elem.clientHeight;
  var scrollDist = targetScroll - startScroll;
  
  easing = easing || (x => x);
  function scrollFunc(t)
  {
    if (startTime === null) startTime = t;
    
    var frac = (t - startTime) / time;
    if (frac > 1) frac = 1;
    
    elem.scrollTop = startScroll + Math.ceil(scrollDist * easing(frac));
    
    if (frac < 0.99999)
      requestAnimationFrame(scrollFunc);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(scrollFunc);
}

// Do the scroll
scrollToBottom(document.getElementById("data"), 10000, easeInOutSine);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to scrollSmoothToBottom

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  const scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);

  const scrollSmoothToBottom = () => {
  $(scrollingElement).animate({
  scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight,
  }, 500);
 }
 scrollSmoothToBottom();
})
```