# How do i make a automatic scroll when people go on a page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

How do I make a automatic scroll when people go on a page?

Here's my current code.

```
function jumpScroll() {
    window.scroll(0,150); // horizontal and vertical scroll targets
}
```

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837676/smooth-auto-scroll-by-using-javascript

Comment: Try this `<body onLoad="jumpScroll()">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change scroll to scrollBy

Make sure and add

```
onLoad="jumpScroll()"
```

to your body tags.

Comment: Do i put code like          onLoad="jumpScroll(60)"   ?

Comment: No, jumpScroll is the function you defined which will be called onLoad

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please Try the Below Code:

```
function jumpScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,150); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('jumpScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
```

To being scrolling automatically when the page loads, add the following code to the body tag:

```
<body onLoad="jumpScroll()">
```

To begin scrolling when prompted by the user, call the function from a link or button:

```
<a href="javascript:jumpScroll()">Scroll Page</a>
```

Button:

```
<input type="button" onClick="jumpScroll()" value="Scroll Page">
```

Comple Source: [Automatic Scroll](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like this now and see how it works... http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/navigation/quick.html