# Auto Scroll enable and disable link

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

How do I modify the following script to be able to stop and enable auto-scrolling using a simple text link like this html link
`<a href="javascript:stopScroll()">Stop Scrolling</a>` ?
Thanks.

```
<script>
(function() {
   'use strict';

   var dbh,sto,num=3,temp=0,scrolldelay=70;

function init(){ 
    dbh=document.body.offsetHeight;
    pageScroll();
 }

function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,num);
    temp+=num;
if((temp>=dbh)||(temp<=0)){
    num=-num;
 }
   sto=setTimeout(function(){pageScroll();},scrolldelay);
 }
   window.addEventListener?
   window.addEventListener('load',init,false):
   window.attachEvent('onload',init);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script I finally got to work is a little different from my original post. This seems to work but not as fluid in Google Chrome for some reason.

Here's what I finally put together and there are people to thank here as well...

```
<script>
var xMax, yMax, xNeg=1, yNeg=1;

function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(1 * xNeg, 1 * yNeg);
    if(xMax == window.scrollX)xNeg = xNeg * -1;
    if(yMax == window.scrollY)yNeg = xNeg * -1;
    scrolldelay = setTimeout(pageScroll,1);
    console.log(window.scrollY);
    xMax = window.scrollX;
    yMax = window.scrollY;
}
function stopScroll() {
        clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
}
</script>
```

Now, for the body section...

```
<a href="javascript:stopScroll()">Stop or Slow Auto Scroll.</a><br>
<a href="javascript:pageScroll()">Start or Speed Up Auto Scroll.</a>
```

The main script came from another article here at stackoverflow, SajithNair 
( [This Article Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188541/how-to-toggle-auto-scroll-function-reverse-page-scroll) )

stopScroll() function was merely added and the function call pageScroll() was just invoked as a link. This was demonstrated in [this Article.](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html)