# Automatically Scrolling a webpage with animating div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a web app. I have created 25 divs.

I have Used jquery `fadeIn()` by which divs are gradually made and displayed one after another on screen.

But problem is that when 25 divs have been created, scroll is created due to which first 4 divs can be seen but the remaining can't be seen until user scroll the page.

I want that as one by one div is created, the page should automatically scroll to the div recently created and so on this process should be continued until the last div is created.

Comment: This would be very annoying to the user who is using the website. Or are you making a sidebar which auto scrolls like twitter feed?

Comment: No actually this webpage will display the solution of mathematical questions . The steps of the questions are solved in divs. So obviously solving step by step lot of divs will be made down the page. And i want to scroll them automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`$('html,body').scrollTop($(".answer.visible:last").offset().top);`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".answer").hide();
  $('#demo').click(function(e) {
    var _div = $('.answer[style*="display: none"]:first');
    if (_div.length) {
      _div.fadeIn();
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: _div.offset().top
        },
        'slow');
    } else {
      $(this).text('Done..!');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#demo {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.answer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="demo">Click here</button>
<div class="answer">1</div>
<div class="answer">2</div>
<div class="answer">3</div>
<div class="answer">4</div>
<div class="answer">5</div>
<div class="answer">6</div>
<div class="answer">7</div>
<div class="answer">8</div>
<div class="answer">9</div>
<div class="answer">10</div>
<div class="answer">11</div>
<div class="answer">12</div>
<div class="answer">13</div>
<div class="answer">14</div>
<div class="answer">15</div>
<div class="answer">16</div>
<div class="answer">17</div>
<div class="answer">18</div>
<div class="answer">19</div>
<div class="answer">20</div>
<div class="answer">21</div>
<div class="answer">22</div>
<div class="answer">23</div>
<div class="answer">24</div>
<div class="answer">25</div>
```

I think this looks pretty cool when we use slideDown+scrollTop. [Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3otp7j/)

**Documentations**

To get the coordinates
http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Set vertical position of the scroll bar
https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Set horizontal position of the scroll bar
https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/

Comment: Works perfect in my Firefox v 37. Click the button to see the animation.

Comment: Now it works, you changed it so that all divs are already in the DOM, maybe that was the problem.

Comment: if want to move horizontally then?

Comment: @Zeshan_SE https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/ to set scrollbar position. `_div.offset().left` to get the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link here
[smooth auto scroll by using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837676/smooth-auto-scroll-by-using-javascript)
Using this you could create something like this here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mrc0sp5j/

The main point is, that you create a scrolling-function using

```
window.scrollBy or window.scrollTo
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp
With jQuery .last or .eq you can specify which element you want to scroll to

```
$(".mydivobjects").eq(x).position().top
```

Hope this helps
cheers

Comment: ok now if we want to control it with a button then what code should be there?

Comment: You could pack the scrolling-function (see fiddle) in a button, like $("#button").click(function() { scrolltofunction(); }));