# auto smooth scroll to down - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

i want add Play button and stop button for scroll down with smoothly moev without cutting

```html
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
<body>

<ilayer id="body">
    <div style=" position: fixed; color:red;" ><button>play scroll down</button> <button>stop scroll dwon</button> </div>
test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br><br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>test <br>
</ilayer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you checked this post yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837676/smooth-auto-scroll-by-using-javascript

Comment: @Termonator145 those are all really bad answers

Comment: yes For this post is all bad

Comment: @JackKing what is `<ilayer>`? Do you have clients that use Netscape 4?