# How to make a website scroll vertically slowly while still keeping control of scrolling

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web, scroll, autoscroll

I am making a Ruby on Rails website.
I would like to implement a functionality that when a user clicked a button, the website would scroll down slowly.
I have looked at similar options but most of what I've found takes control of the scrolling away from the user until it ends.
I want the user to still be able to scroll wherever they want to while that automatic scroll is happening.
Here is an example: https://www.ukulele-tabs.com/uke-songs/vance-joy/riptide-uke-tab-31868.html

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: based on your question, this example seems far away, please be clear

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm not sure what you mean. In the example website, there is a box that says "AutoScroll" and has 6 buttons. Each button starts scrolling the website down at different speeds. While it is scrolling, I can still scroll with my mouse wheel on with the scroll bar on the side. I did not make that example website nor am I related to it.

Comment: take a look at this, you might find the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837676/smooth-auto-scroll-by-using-javascript

Comment: I will try later and update the question if it does. Thanks!